# Sonar dead store to local variable NumberFormat java

Tags: java, sonarqube, number-formatting

I have this method;

```
private static String formatVolumeForLife(String rateBasisValue, String volumeValue) {
    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat();
    if(PER_UNIT.equals(rateBasisValue) || PER_DEPENDENT_PER_UNIT_PER_MONTH.equals(rateBasisValue)){
        formatter = new DecimalFormat(FORMAT_NUMBER_WITH_COMMA);
    } else {
        formatter = new DecimalFormat(FORMAT_CURRENCY);
    }
    String formattedVolume = formatter.format(Double.parseDouble(volumeValue));
    return formattedVolume;
}
```

Sonar complains with "Sonar dead store to local variable formatter".

Do I need to change the NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat();?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The created object is never used. Change the code to

```
private static String formatVolumeForLife(String rateBasisValue, String volumeValue) {
    NumberFormat formatter;
    if(PER_UNIT.equals(rateBasisValue) || PER_DEPENDENT_PER_UNIT_PER_MONTH.equals(rateBasisValue)){
        formatter = new DecimalFormat(FORMAT_NUMBER_WITH_COMMA);
    } else {
        formatter = new DecimalFormat(FORMAT_CURRENCY);
    }
    return formatter.format(Double.parseDouble(volumeValue));
}
```